# two network (one lan and one via usb internet)

Tags: networking, internet, lan

I don't want the LAN network to connect to internet only for remote controlling computer, but the remote control computer itself has internet which is via google Fi through USB

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access internet from two interfaces on the same computer but need to use one interface only for perticular remote IP, easiest way to make "route" to that IP using USB internet connection's gateway with higer prority (metric) instead of using  the default gateway from ethernet interface.

If you are using a Windows, you can follow this guide https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/adding-a-tcpip-route-to-the-windows-routing-table/

Comment: I have go through the link before and follow. I have used it and it is not working. I have route my internal network 192.168.3.65 to only local network which I can remotely access (route add 192.168.3.65 mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.3.1 metric 1 if 17) 17 is my network interface and I have delete 0.0.0.0 on my local network, so only via usb that can used to go online and the route is (route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.8.1 metric 1 if 7) 7 is my usb interface. I was using google Fi, and it is not working.

Comment: Could you please add network diagram and outputs of "ipconfig /all" and "route print" ? It will be help to understand the exact situation and the issue.